# Merge multiple SQLite databases using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, sqlite

I have multiple sqlite databases with the same schema, and i want to merge them all together, since i have a unique column and there might be risks of duplicates, i am using `insert or ignore`, in sqlite it would be easy :

```
sqlite3 database.db3
sqlite> attach './db1.db3' as s1;
sqlite> attach './db2.db3' as s2;
sqlite> attach './db3.db3' as s3;
sqlite> insert or ignore into table (c1, c2, c3) select c1, c2, c3 from s1.table;
sqlite> insert or ignore into table (c1, c2, c3) select c1, c2, c3 from s2.table;
sqlite> insert or ignore into table (c1, c2, c3) select c1, c2, c3 from s3.table;
sqlite> .exit
```

I read about dump but i dont want to merge the whole schema, just one table, so i thought about this solution, now till here everything is fine but i need to run all this via a bash,  i tried the following but it doesnt :

```
sqlite3 database.db3 "attach './db1.db3' as s1;"
sqlite3 database.db3 "attach './db2.db3' as s2;"
sqlite3 database.db3 "attach './db3.db3' as s3;"
sqlite3 database.db3 "select count(*) from s1.table;"
sqlite3 database.db3 "select count(*) from s2.table;"
sqlite3 database.db3 "select count(*) from s3.table;"
```

it says `Error: no such table: s1.table`

What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) as shown below:

```
sqlite3 database.db3 << "EOF"
attach './db1.db3' as s1;
attach './db2.db3' as s2;
attach './db3.db3' as s3;
insert or ignore into table (c1, c2, c3) select c1, c2, c3 from s1.table;
insert or ignore into table (c1, c2, c3) select c1, c2, c3 from s2.table;
insert or ignore into table (c1, c2, c3) select c1, c2, c3 from s3.table;
.exit
EOF
```

Alternatively, put all your commands into a file and run it like this:

```
sqlite3 database.db3 < commandsFile
```

Answer (score 3):

1) Create a text file with the lines you want to enter into the sqlite command line program, like this:

```
attach './db1.db3' as s1;
attach './db2.db3' as s2;
attach './db3.db3' as s3;
insert or ignore into table (c1, c2, c3) select c1, c2, c3 from s1.table;
insert or ignore into table (c1, c2, c3) select c1, c2, c3 from s2.table;
insert or ignore into table (c1, c2, c3) select c1, c2, c3 from s3.table;
.exit
```

and then just call `sqlite3 database.db < commands.txt`

2) using shell

```
#!/bin/bash 

sqlite3 database.db <<"EOF"
attach './db1.db3' as s1;
attach './db2.db3' as s2;
attach './db3.db3' as s3;
insert or ignore into table (c1, c2, c3) select c1, c2, c3 from s1.table;
insert or ignore into table (c1, c2, c3) select c1, c2, c3 from s2.table;
insert or ignore into table (c1, c2, c3) select c1, c2, c3 from s3.table;
.exit
EOF
```